# Basic Database Class with PDO functionality

Tags: php, object-oriented

Is my following (very basic) class considered good use for PDO integration?
Or is there a better, more efficient way?

```
class Page {

    public $title;
    public $db;

    public function __construct($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function connect($host, $dbname, $username, $password) {
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);
    }

    public function disconnect() {
        $this->db = null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, my review is going to be all about control.

## Not Enough - Public Property

Just like in the real world, public property can be used by anyone.  If your car was public property anyone could walk into your driveway and do whatever they liked with it.  When you woke up you could not expect to `$this->car->drive()` (What if someone had already taken it and replaced it with `null`?).  If they wanted to they could place a house brick in your driveway pretending that it is your car (good luck driving that).

Public properties remove the encapsulation of state from an object.  I see virtually no place for them in OO.  Protected and Private properties on the other hand are set through using the public interface (the public methods) of an object.  Importantly the public interface is testable, so you can ensure that you will not end up with a brick in your driveway unless you really want that.

## Too Much - Inversion of Control

Your code will benefit from an Inversion of Conrtol (IoC).  You can read about IoC on the web.  There is a good answer on stackoverflow with code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3140/567663).

With IoC and the protected properties your code becomes:

```
class Page {

    protected $title;
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($db, $title) {
        $this->db    = $db;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
}
```

Your code is no longer dependent on the specific database setup to function correctly.  Your page will use any database connection that it is given.  This has big benefits when it comes to unit testing.  See [Miško Hevery - How to Think About the “new” Operator with Respect to Unit Testing](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/).

I have another answer that covers similar things with an extra part on injecting interfaces [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/9505/7585).

Comment: +1 inversion of control as applied here is also referred to as dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

**Unused properties**

You shoult not set `$this->title` in the `__construct()` method unless you are planning on using it.It would be better if you set this value in the particular method that is planning on using this data.

**Visibility**

The first thing I noticed when I looked at this code is that these properties  `public $title;
    public $db;`are indeed public. It would be best if you change the visibility to private to ensure that you have more control over the state of these values.

**Exception handling**

In your *connect* method you are creating a new PDO object without handling any errors that may occur. The correct approach is to use the [PDOException class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)
to handle this error.

An example:

```
try
{
  $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $username, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  die($e->getMessage());
}
```

**Commenting**

It's always good to practice making comments in your code to ensure that its easy to follow and if another developer should use your class they will be able to understand exactly whats taking place. [phpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) is a good tool that can be used to generate documentation.

**Querying**

Is this the complete class? I ask this because it seems as if a query function is missing. Making queries with PDO have been simplified thus can implement a simple query method to  retrieve to access your database.

```
public function query($query)
{
  if($query)
  {
    $current_query->$this->db->prepare($query);
    $current_query->execute();
    $result->$current_query->fetchAll();

    return $result;
  }
  else
  return false;
}
```

I hope my answers helps somewhat if they are any concerns or errors one can just leave a comment, I am open to criticism.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense! I left exception handling out, because I'm just starting to learn OO. And I left out querying because I thought it was redundant, because PDO already has native methods to do that. That's why I also made a `public $db`

Comment: ok great! glad I could help.

Comment: @fishbaitfood: Would like to clarify a few things. Doccomments are good, inline comments are not. They clutter your code. Most IDEs know how to collapse doccomments all at once so they are out of the way. As for title, I agree that shouldn't be the sole item in the constructor, but following Paul's example should fix this. And finally, as you have already mentioned, adding the query functionality would be redundant, as would creating a class just to instantiate a database. If you are planning on doing more this is fine, but as is this is redundant.